# rtp streaming using vlcj - only one directional streaming worked

Tags: java, vlc, vlcj

I wrote a java realtime app using vlcj for transferring prerecorded video clips. I used two Windows 10 laptops, C1 and C2 for testing.

The test results:
1). used C1 as the streamer, C2 the receiver, it worked fine;
2). used C2 as the streamer, and C1 the receiver, no data streaming at all. mediaPlayer.isPlaying() always returned true, and never quit. I also checked the MediaPlayerEventListener.buffering(...), and no buffering data cache.

It's assumed that the rtp use udp protocol for both data and control communications. Thus the rtp's port number should be that of the underlying data udp.

As a test, before I began streaming the video between C1 and C2, I opened a separate udp socket communication using the same ports, and each side indeed received the msg from another side. It implied the communications between them could be two directional. No problem for that. Therefore, NAT or firewall relevant issues would be excluded.

### The code snippet on the sender side is like,

```
public class StreamSender {

   private MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = null;
   private HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
 
   public void streamFile(String absoluteFilePath, String remoteIpAddress, int remotePort) {

      String options = formatRtpStream(remoteIpAddress, remotePort);
      mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(absoluteFilePath);
      mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();
      mediaPlayer.playMedia(absoluteFilePath, 
         options,             
         ":no-sout-rtp-sap",
                ":no-sout-standard-sap",
                ":sout-all",
                ":sout-keep"
        );
    }

    private String formatRtpStream(String remoteIpAddress, int remotePort) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(150);

        sb.append(":sout=#rtp{dst=");
        sb.append(rmoteIpAddress);
        sb.append(",port=");
        sb.append(remotePort);
        sb.append(",mux=ts}");
        
        return sb.toString();
    }
...
}
```

---

the receiver side's code is like,

```
public class StreamReceiver {
    private EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    private MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = null;

    public void initializeMediaPlayer() {
        mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface = mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas);
        mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayerForWinAndNixOS.setVideoSurface(videoSurface);
        mediaPlayer.setPlaySubItems(true);
        mediaPlayer.addMediaPlayerEventListener(this);
    }

    // url is like, rtp://@:21796
    // with 21796 being the remotePort
    

    public void lazyStartPlayer(String url`enter code here`) {
        initializeMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        mediaPlayer.playMedia(url);
    }

...
}
```

Appreciate any helps.

It has been noticed that C1,which received streaming data from C2, with a hardware card like,
[322c1cf8] avcodec decoder: Using D3D11VA (Intel(R) HD Graphics 520, vendor 8086(Intel), device 1916, revision 7) for hardware decoding.

While C2 which can't receive from C1, with a different hardware card,
[1cec80a8] avcodec decoder: Using D3D11VA (Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600, vendor 8086(Intel), device 416, revision 6) for hardware decoding.

Not sure if those decoding hardware made a difference.

But when both computers are within an intranet network (behind the same router), then no problem.

Comment: I also tried to use UDP to send the file by packets from C2 to C1, and it worked fine. it implied it's not a NAT or firewall issue. With the same remote endpoint, using rtp streaming by vlcj's mediaPlayer failed to work: MediaPlayer.playMedia(absoluteFilePath, 
                options,             
          ":no-sout-rtp-sap",
                 ":no-sout-standard-sap",
                 ":sout-all",
                 ":ttl=1",
                 ":sout-keep"
    );

Answer (score 0):

I read that you tried udp socket communication on the ports, but i would suggest that you should try the rtp streaming with installed vlc player clients (it can broadcast, and playback too). This way you can prove that it's not a network problem (it looks like a firewall, or occupied port issue to me).

Your code looks fine, so I can't really pinpoint other issues (maybe double check urls).

(This should be a comment, but my rep is low.)